# dynamically add array to style_formats array within a function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to add custom styles to wordpress using dynamic arrays.

My question is how can i add the two arrays to the style_formats array within the 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' function dynamically?

```
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  

  $style_formats = array(  

  array(  
      'title' => '.translation',  
      'block' => 'blockquote',  
      'classes' => 'translation',
      'wrapper' => true,

  ),  

//add arrays here dynamically

  );  

  $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

  return $init_array;  

} 


//arrays to add dynamically
array(  
    'title' => '⇠.rtl',  
    'block' => 'blockquote',  
    'classes' => 'rtl',
    'wrapper' => true,
),

array(  
    'title' => '.ltr⇢',  
    'block' => 'blockquote',  
    'classes' => 'ltr',
    'wrapper' => true,
),
```

Comment: Pass arrays to the function, and add them inside of it.

Comment: you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to add arrays.

Comment: So, you want to add two array to $style_formats array or array within array to $style_formats ??